# Как заставить Retrofit работать с @Path после вопросительного знака в ссылке?

Tags: retrofit2

Имеется сайт, бекенд работает на Java, ссылки выглядят так:

```
http://site.ru/user/192718/?wicket:interface=:5:addFriend::ILinkListener::
```

Бывают также замудренные ссылки, где в конце вообще всякая каша... Изначально я все написал на `Retrofit` ничего не тестируя. Позже выяснилось что аннотация `Path` не работает после вопросительного знака. Переписал все на другую библиотеку и получился дикий ужас. Сейчас обратно смотрю в сторону `Retrofit` и не могу понять, как заставить работать аннотацию @Path после вопросительного знака? Или может, какая-то другая есть для этих дел. Или вообще написать свою.

```
@GET("http://site.ru/user/{userId}/?wicket:interface=:{session}:addFriend::ILinkListener::")
Call<Document> addFriend(@Path("userId") long userId, @Path("session") long session);
```

Неохота делать всякие методы для формирования ссылок или использовать аннотацию @Url. Все это будет выглядить не профитно

Открыто [Issue #2535](https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/2535) на гитхабе.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Придумал "хак". Пишем все методы интерфейса, указывая вместо вопросительного знака его перевёрнутый аналог (можно любой другой, но он более похож)

```
@GET("user/{userId}/¿wicket:interface=:{session}:addFriend::ILinkListener::")
Call<Document> addFriend(@Path("userId") long userId, @Path("session") long session);
```

И пишем такой вот `Interceptor`:

```
public class URLInterceptor implements Interceptor {
@Override
public Response intercept(Interceptor.Chain chain) throws IOException {
    Request original = chain.request();
    String originalUrl = original.url().toString();
    Request request = original.newBuilder().
        method(original.method(), original.body()).
        url(originalUrl.replace(URLEncoder.encode("¿", "UTF-8"), "?")).
        build();
        Response response = chain.proceed(request);
        return response;
    }
}
```

Таким образом, `Retrofit` изначально не знает, что есть вопросительный знак...

***ХАК ЕЩЕ НЕ ПРОВЕРЕН***